# dynamic-require a module with respect to the current module path in Racket (Or how to find the current module path in Racket)

Tags: module, racket

If I want to optionally require a module at runtime, I can use [`dynamic-require`'[1](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=dynamic-require#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._dynamic-require%29%29). This works great if I want to require a package that has been installed, for example:

```
(dynamic-require 'racket/match 'match)
```

This will (provided I have `racket/match` installed), require `racket/match` and evaluate to the `match` binding in that library.

However, I run into trouble when I want to require a local, non installed module.  Let's say I have some module called `eat.rkt`, which provides one function: `bite`:

```
#lang racket ;; eat.rkt
(provide bite)
(define (bite) "Nom nom")
```

Now lets say we want to make a `lunch.rkt` module that requires `eat.rkt`, and calls the function. Furthermore, lets suppose I put them in the same directory:

```
#lang racket ;; lunch.rkt
(require "eat.rkt")
(bite) ; => Nom Nom
```

This is fine because I used static require, but this falls apart when I want to do a `dynamic-require`:

```
#lang racket ;; lunch2.rkt
(define bite (dynamic-require "eat.rkt" 'bite)
(bite) ; => Nom Nom
```

While this appears to be fine, it turns out that the module required by `dynamic-require` is NOT required based on the module's path, but on [`current-directory`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=current-directory#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-directory%29%29). So, if I run the program in the directory the module is defined, that's fine, but if I'm in another directory, everything breaks:

```
$ racket lunch2.rkt
"Nom Nom"
$ cd snacks/
$ racket ../lunch2.rkt
; default-load-handler: cannot open module file
```

Obviously I could just change the `current-directory` to this module's directory if I know where it is. But if I don't know this module's path, is there any way to get it? Or, more directly, is it possible to `dynamic-require` a module relative to the requiring's module path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`define-runtime-path`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=define-runtime-path#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fruntime-path..rkt%29._define-runtime-path%29%29) form defines a path that will be available at runtime and is independent of the `current-directory`. Use it to define the path to the module you want to require dynamically, for example:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/runtime-path)
(define-runtime-path eat "eat.rkt")
(dynamic-require eat 'bite)
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to `dynamic-require` a module relative to the current module path (which is to say the path where the module is saved), is to get that module path and append it your relative module.

You can do this with [`#%variable-reference`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Locations____variable-reference.html?q=%23%25variable-reference#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._~23~25variable-reference%29%29) and [`variable-reference->module-path-index`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html?q=variable-reference-%3Emodule-path-index#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._variable-reference-~3emodule-path-index%29%29). (You may also want to use [`variable-reference->resolved-module-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html?q=variable-reference-%3Eresolved-module-path#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._variable-reference-~3eresolved-module-path%29%29) for other situations, but we will not do it here.) Composing these two functions gives us a `module-path-index?` to the module being defined. (Or in general, the module that the `#%variable-reference` came from.)

So, we can a variable like:

```
(define here (variable-reference->module-path-index (#%variable-reference)))
```

Now all that is left is to compose this `here` path with the relative path to the module we want to require. We are looking for the module path analogy of `build-path`, if you will.

It turns out that the function we are looking for is: [`module-path-index-join`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=module-path-index-join#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._module-path-index-join%29%29), which takes a base path and a relative path and appends them together. The result will look something like:

```
(module-path-index-join "eat.rkt" here)
```

(Yes, it is backwards of what you would expect from `build-path`, but the base path comes second for this function.)

The resulting module, `lunch3.rkt` looks like:

```
#lang racket
(define here (variable-reference->module-path-index (#%variable-reference)))
(define bite (dynamic-require (module-path-index-join "eat.rkt" here) 'bite))
```

And now `lunch3.rkt` will require `eat.rkt` relative to where its defined, not based on the `current-directory`:

```
$ racket lunch3.rkt
"Nom Nom"
$ cd snacks/
$ racket ../lunch3.rkt
"Nom Nom"
```

Thank you to Matthew Flatt for helping with this answer.

Comment: There's also `define-runtime-module-path-index`, which (IIRC) also cooperates with `raco distribute` and friends.

Comment: Can confirm, `define-runtime-module-path-index` works like a charm.
Maybe it was added after this question?